# AES weird difference between encryption and decryption speed

Tags: android, performance, aes

I am writing app that need to encrypt and decrypt files. My problem is that decryption is done about 5 times slower than encryption. I've stripped all file read/write operations and benchmarked only crypto processes. The results was very surprising:

Encrypting 1.5 MB byte array with `encryptionCipher.doFinal()` (which is instance of javax.crypto.Cipher)

`~1600 ms`

Decrypting 1.5 MB byte array with `decryptionCipher.doFinal()` (which is instance of javax.crypto.Cipher)

`~5800 ms`

I am very surprised, because as I know AES decryption and encryption are symmetric processes and there should be no difference in encryption and decryption speed.

I am using `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` cipher with 256 bit key.

What can cause this?

Comment: Actually is even weirder as CBC decryps mode should be faster than encrypt (decrypt of blocks can be parallelized) [CBC Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)

Comment: Profile the app to see what is taking time. Could be inefficient implementation. Or, include the Spongy Castle provider in your app and  add timing log statements. Compare with same code on desktop machine with different providers (Sun/Oracle, Bouncy Castle, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Encryption and decryption can take time in android (because of code conversion and low available resources). JNI is preferred for tasks like this. Use openssl routines to encrypt and decrypt and call them in your java code via JNI interface.